# Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException While trying to create a reply

Tags: botframework

I'm using the Microsoft Bot Framework with C# and I'm trying to create a reply message with an image like so:

```
IMessageActivity m = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]").ToList();
var src = images[10].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
Attachment att = new Attachment();
att.ContentType = "image";
att.ContentUrl = src;
m.Attachments.Add(att);
await context.PostAsync(m);
context.Wait(MessageReceived);
```

I know that the image source is being extracted correctly but I still get the error:

```
Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException
```

What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?
I expect to have a message with the image attached but instead I just get the default bot code error message.
Edit: this is the exception message - 'ReplyToId' cannot be null.

Comment: are you doing this from a dialog or the messages controller?

Comment: `att.ContentType = "image";` may also not be a valid content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a message using the **Activity.CreateMessageActivity()** then you need to specify the details of user account(ToId,ToName), bot account(FromId, FromName) and conversation(conservationId, channelId).

eg:

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(toId,toName);
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(fromId, fromName);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl));

IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conversationId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelId))
{
    message.ChannelId = channelId;
}
else
{
    conversationId = (await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync( botAccount, userAccount)).Id;
}
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId);
message.Text = "The text you want to send";
//You can add your attachment here
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

Looking at your code it looks like you can access the **context** of the Dialog since you are posting the message using context.PostAsync, so the easier way would be to send a message using the context since the context will already contain the details of user, bot and conversation.

You can do this by using context.MakeMessage()

eg:

```
IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();

var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]").ToList();
var src = images[10].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
Attachment att = new Attachment();
att.ContentType = "image/png";
att.ContentUrl = src;

reply.Attachments.Add(att);
await context.PostAsync(reply);
context.Wait(MessageReceived);
```

Comment: Is there any way to resize the image?